# Hibernate - Fetch from database according to language

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an MVC app which is aimed to be internationalized. I have a table `MY_TABLE` containing a field `word` that I would like to translate in several languages. I created the following model:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    -- other fields that don't need to be translated
);
CREATE TABLE LANGUAGE(
    id VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY -- eg en
);
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_WORD_TRANSLATION(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    language_id VARCHAR(4),
    my_table_id int,
    word_translation VARCHAR(100),
    FOREIGN KEY(language_id) REFERENCES LANGUAGE(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(my_table_id) REFERENCES MY_TABLE(id)
);
```

Now with Hibernate I created the corresponding classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="LANGUAGE")
public class Language {
    private String id;

    public Language(){}
    public Language(String id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
} 

@Entity
@Table(name="MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable {
    private int id;

    public MyTable(){}
    public MyTable(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="MY_TABLE_WORD_TRANSLATION")
public class MyTableWordTranslation {
    private int id;
    private String translation;
    private Language language;
    private MyTable myTable;

    public MyTableWordTranslation() {}
    public RegionNameTranslation(int id, String translation, Language language, MyTable myTable) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.translation = translation;
        this.language = language;
        this.myTable = myTable;
    }
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }
    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="language_id")
    public Language getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }
    public void setLanguage(Language language) {
        this.language = language;
    }   
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="my_table_id")
    public MyTable getMyTable() {
        return myTable;
    }
    public void setMyTable(MyTable myTable) {
        this.myTable = myTable;
    }
}
```

So the question is how to map into MyTable the field MyTableWordTranslation in order to get only the translation I need:

- Is it in the DAO class, in the HQL queries but then, what query should I write? For now I have `SELECT mytable FROM MyTable mytable`
- I tried to map with `@OneToMany` with a `@Where` filter, but how can I set a parameter in this filter: `@Where(clause="language_id = 'en'")`? The language is specified into the GET resquest from the client.

Thanks

Comment: Your language table has only one column which is the language code. If you are not planning to add any more columns there, then I suggest you get rid of it. Right now it only adds to complexity with little benefit. There are a lot of libraries that contain the list of country codes.

Comment: @A.Ebrahim yes but I want to add other columns to this table, I wanted to keep my example simple. Thanks for the remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your mapping works I think you may want to write a query using the MyTableWordTranslation entity since it owns the many to one side, it will get the "MyTable" object you're looking for.

> - Is it in the DAO class, in the HQL queries but then, what query    should I write? For now I have SELECT mytable FROM MyTable mytable
> - I tried to map with @OneToMany with a @Where filter, but how can I set a parameter in this filter: @Where(clause="language_id =
>     'en'")? The language is specified into the GET resquest from the
>     client.

In scenarios where your query isn't being built at runtime, you can annotate your entity with a @NamedQueries annotation. Inside your annotation, you can provide an array of @NamedQuery annotations that have "name" and "query" attributes. The name attribute allows you to be able to reference your query you provide for the query value. In this particular example, it'd look something like this.

`@NamedQueries(value = {@NamedQuery(name = "MyTableWordTranslation.getWordByLanguage", query = "SELECT mtwt.mytable FROM MyTableWordTranslation mtwt where mtwt.myTable.id=:wordId and     mtwt.language.id = :languageId"),
    ...more queries,
    .,
    .})
    @Entity
    @Table(name="MY_TABLE_WORD_TRANSLATION")
    public class MyTableWordTranslation {`

Now when you want to use this query, you can access it through your entity manager in your DAO like so.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("MyTableWordTranslation.getWordByLanguage");
query.setParameter("wordId", wordId);
query.setParameter("languageId", languageId);

MyTable mt = (MyTable) query.getSingleResult();
```

Here is a link that should help better explain NamedQueries: https://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-named-query